# Setup of Azure Application Gateway on multiple sites

Tags: azure, iis, azure-application-gateway, multiple-sites, session-affinity

We have 2 Azure VMs running IIS and hosting 50+ .Net web applications (Webforms, MVC, WCF & ASMX). Both of the 2 VMs are identical and all sites are configured using a hostname ([subdomain].domain.com) on port 443 and requiring SSL.
11 of these sites are legacy and require afinity because of session state, all other sites don't and can be randomly loadbalanced.

All of the sites run perfectly on each of the 2 servers.

Now we would like to put an Application Gateway in front of the 2 VMs to provide loadbalancing, https redirect, WAF, ...

Can we configure 1 Application Gateway to do all this and make sure the affinity is only valid for those 11 sites and not for all of them and also do the https redirect?
Or do we need to configure 2 Application Gateways, 1 for the 11 affinity-dependent sites and 1 for the remaining and then have dns point to 1 of the Gateways?

Comment: how do you determine to which site to route request?

Comment: @4c74356b41 on IIS you mean? There we have the host names to point to the correct site. Or do you mean on the gateway itself, then I don't quite understand what you mean?

Comment: on the gateway.

Comment: @4c74356b41 that is one of the things I'm looking for

Comment: well, how can I help you if you dont know what do you need? is it path based routing or domain or ??

Answer (score 0):

1. In Application gateway you can create 100 Listeners (For WAF enabled
   SKUs). So you should be able to accommodate your setup with one
   Application gateway.

   2. When you are creating HTTP settings, you can choose whether to
      enable Cookie based affinity or not.
   3. Application gateway has all the feature you requested, like HTTP to
      HTTPS redirection, WAF protection.

So you should be able to deploy an Application Gateway and configure to make your setup work.